# IE6 using Multiple IEs doesn't let me edit textboxes

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-6

Not sure if this counts as programming related, it's a tool that I use.

I've got [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) installed so I can test the sites I make on IE6 for those people who require it, but recently IE6 is not letting me enter into any textboxes, they're acting as if they're all disabled.

Has anyone else encountered this probelem and/or know of a solution.  I've already tried uninstalling & re-installing multiple ie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovered in the comments on the tredosoft site that installing [IE8 breaks textbox & textareas](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE?page=6) in the Multiple IE browser. I uninstalled IE8 & it's fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Multipe IE for my testing but lately I am trying out [SuperPreview](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/03/microsoft-announces-superpreview-for-ie-browser-testing/).

SuperPreview is a new free standalone application from Microsoft (still in beta) which enables you to see how your websites will look across different versions of Internet Explorer making migration from IE6 to 7 and 8 much easier than before, without have to start up a Virtual Machine to run IE6, or have a separate computer dedicated to running IE6.

Comment: Does it just take snapshots or can you step through a site to test functionality?

Comment: I've installed it, and while it's very useful for some things, it does only do static snapshots :(  Oh well, new virtual machine it is

Comment: http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm works great for me (it runs actual versions of the browsers so you get interactive pages and not just static snapshots).

Comment: @Glenn Slaven - IIRC it just does rendering - thus testing out your page interaction, JavaScript & AJAX is a no-go. http://www.spoon.net/ used to be the best way to test all versions of IE (and any other Windows based browser) but MSFT shut the IE part of it down.

Answer (score 1):

Use the app compat VHD's that Microsoft makes available for free.  Virtual PC is free too.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

You can't take a random subset of system dlls and host them side-by-side and expect things to work.  It's like expecting the engine from a 1982 Corvette to work in a 2005 Audi S4.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is just one of the weird little behavioural/scripting weirdnesses that affects multiple-IE setups.

Sadly the virtual machine method is the only reliable way to test web browser interaction (as opposed to just rendering) across different versions of IE. (Thanks for integrating that one into the OS Microsoft. Yay.)

Still, it's a good excuse to tell your boss to justify a more powerful workstation, eh...

Answer (score 0):

I just installed [IE Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) and so far it works much better than Multiple IE for me.  I still had to uninstall IE8 to get form inputs to work, but it comes with a standalone version so I can still use 8 for testing.

It has a crapload of versions too (much more than Multiple IE).  If you're looking for some old-school fun, fire up 1.5 and visit just about any site ever.